# Problem with building nuxtjs app with gsap-bonus.tgz in heroku

Tags: vue.js, heroku, nuxt.js, gsap

**Hi!
i have issue from heroku cause of gsap-bonus.tgz.
any help ?
I mean, i tried to buid my project in heroku but i've got gsap issue with gsap-bonus.tgz
thanks**

> ```
> Enumerating objects: 62, done.
> Counting objects: 100% (62/62), done.
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads
> Compressing objects: 100% (56/56), done.
> Writing objects: 100% (62/62), 4.79 MiB | 520.00 KiB/s, done.
> Total 62 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
> remote: Compressing source files... done.
> remote: Building source:
> remote: 
> remote: -----> Node.js app detected
> remote:        
> remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
> remote:        
> remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
> remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
> remote:        NODE_ENV=production
> remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
> remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
> remote:        
> remote: -----> Installing binaries
> remote:        engines.node (package.json):  v13.0.1
> remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
> remote:        
> remote:        Resolving node version v13.0.1...
> remote:        Downloading and installing node 13.0.1...
> remote:        Using default npm version: 6.12.0
> remote:        
> remote: -----> Installing dependencies
> remote:        Installing node modules
> remote:        npm ERR! code ENOENT
> remote:        npm ERR! syscall stat
> remote:        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_54b2ab671528038c46f664c61dba23e0/gsap-bonus.tgz
> remote:        npm ERR! errno -2
> remote:        npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/tmp/build_54b2ab671528038c46f664c61dba23e0/gsap-bonus.tgz'
> remote:        npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> remote:        npm ERR! enoent 
> remote:        
> remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.8nKRT/_logs/2020-04-29T09_45_17_878Z-debug.log
> ```

Someone has the same issue ? 
because all myu projects were with gsap-bonus.tgz

it's my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "gsap": "file:gsap-bonus.tgz",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-scrollmagic": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-jest": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "v13.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: The error says that gsap-bonus.tgz does not exist where it says that it does. Without more details we can't help

Comment: Zach Saucier thanks for your message. i can't really understand why that does not exist because i install gsap-bonus.tgz by download file... i've add my package.json above.

Comment: Did you `npm install`?

Comment: of course but it's not working when it's push on heroku but locally it's work